# What's the best way to load 2 unaligned 64-bit values into an sse register with SSSE3?

Tags: sse, simd, intrinsics

There are 2 pointers to 2 unaligned 8 byte chunks to be loaded into an xmm register. If possible, using intrinsics. And if possible, without using an auxiliary register. Without pinsrd. (SSSE Core 2)

Comment: Are the 64-bit values contiguous in memory? Or are they scattered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `msvc` [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4wz829a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it looks like you can do the following:

```
__m128d xx;                   // an uninitialised xmm register 
xx = _mm_loadh_pd(xx, ptra);  // load the higher 64 bits from (unaligned) ptra
xx = _mm_loadl_pd(xx, ptrb);  // load the lower 64 bits from (unaligned) ptrb
```

Loading from unaligned storage (in my experience) is very much slower than loading from aligned pointers, so you properly wouldn't want to be doing this type of operation too often - if you really want higher performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know those supported unaligned access. Thanks for the link too, very informative.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to have a _mm_load_sd(ptrb) and then _mm_loadh_pd (... ptra) to avoid a dependency for the first load. (gcc does change it to movsd)

Comment: @alecco: Yeah, could be. This *might* waste time setting the higher `64 bits` to zero, I'm not sure - you'd have to benchmark...

Answer (score 2):

Unaligned access is so much slower than aligned access (at least pre-Nehalem );
you may get better speed by loading the aligned 128 bit words that contain the desired unaligned 64 bit words, then shuffle them to make the result you want.

Assumes:

- you have memory read access to the full 128 word
- the 64 bit words are aligned on at least 32 bit boundaries

e.g. (not tested)

```
int aoff = ptra & 15;
int boff = ptrb & 15;
__m128 va = _mm_load_ps( (char*)ptra - aoff ); 
__m128 vb = _mm_load_ps( (char*)ptrb - boff ); 

switch ( (aoff<<4) | boff ) 
{
    case 0:  _mm_shuffle_ps(va,vb, ...
```

The number of cases depends on whether you can assume 64 bit alignment

Comment: Yes, DarkShikari has an interesting post on this. But it would consume too many registers for this specific code. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea if this has ever been a win in practice? I googled for this idea and ended up here :)

Comment: I can't help but feel you are accessing memory outside the range pointed to by `ptra` and `ptrb`. If those pointers are heap addresses, then there's no guarantee there's a page backing the under-read or over-read.

Comment: @jww,  yes, thus the "Assumes"